# SharePoint 2016 InplaceSearchQuery cant Work in _layouts/15

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm new to SharePoint.

When I using the InPlaceSeach in SharePoint it's does not shown me the results as I want.

Its only display the all the items in my list without filtering.

Here with SharePoint InPlaceSearch Query.
The Query had any wrong?

```
https://mvponduty.com/XXXX/XXX/XX/_layouts/15/inplview.aspx?List=9cf05e04-45bc-4ef1-9ed8-b75a71a9010f&view=4993B60A-BBCE-4A67-BF93-EFE3E405019D&InplaceSearchQuery=Devops
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/Lists/MyList1/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=LinkTitle&FilterValue1=test1
```

Or **POST** request

```
/_layouts/15/inplview.aspx?List={5241E6C6-2E10-48B5-BB34-18338C2C0857}&View={11F0B1C2-89FB-4E74-8E84-79D59029EF16}&ViewCount=0&IsXslView=TRUE&IsCSR=TRUE&InplaceSearchQuery=test1
```

Comment: The first one is correct but how can I get it in XML Format? Thank you

Comment: The error display 403 FORBIDDEN